# 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence' while using scipy.spacial.distance function cdist

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scipy

I am trying to compute the distance between vectors in two pandas dataframes using `cdist` from `scipy.spatial.distance`, but the output is all wrong and I can't pinpoint where is fails. This is actually a follow up on the question [Problems computing cdist of two columns in two different dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679806/problems-computing-cdist-of-two-columns-in-two-different-dataframes)

So, my original dataframes are of the type:

```
df_sample = 
                                             Fingerprint
1272    [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]
657    [1.44, 12.0, 10.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.23, 4.36, 15.0]
806   [4.58, 13.09, 15.46, 3.59, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 6.31]
```

and

```
DF = 
  barcode  \
4538   A4060462000516278   
5043   A4050494272716275   
11663  A4070271111316245   
2701   A4060462848716270   
825    A4060454573516274   
8679   A4060462010016274   
11700  A4060462080916270   
8594   A4060461067716272   
8707   A4060454363916275   
1071   A4060463723916275   

                                                                                                                                    Geopos Ack  
4538     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 15.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 3.0]  
5043   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 12.0, 0.0, 13.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]  
11663      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
2701      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 16.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0]  
825     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 15.0, 0.0, 13.0, 16.0, 0.0, 9.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
8679      [0.0, 4.0, 9.0, 15.0, 10.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 9.0]  
11700     [0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 15.0, 8.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 6.0]  
8594     [12.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 5.0]  
8707       [7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0, 15.0]  
1071      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 15.5, 6.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

(I provide dictionaries for both at the end of the question).

As you can see, they are of different dimension (although the vectors belong to the same space). So, to remedy this I create zero vectors in `df_sample` by doing this:

```
Number_AP = 26
number_zero_vectors = len(DF)-len(df_sample)
df =pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Fingerprint'])
for k in range(number_zero_vectors):
    a = zerolistmaker(Number_AP)
    df = df.append({'Fingerprint':a},ignore_index=True)

df_sample_ = pd.concat([df_sample, df])
```

Hence, `DF` and `df_sample_` have the same shape. My first approach (described in detail in the question mentioned above) was to deal with both columns and all their rows simulataneously, but it did not work. So, my approach now is to deal with both column incrementally (e.g. take the first row of `df_sample_` and compute the distance to every single vectors in `DF`, all this in a loop:

```
distances = []
for i in range(len(df_sample_)):
    a = df_sample_['Fingerprint'][i:i+1]
    print(a)
    for j in range(len(DF)):
        b = DF['Geopos Ack'][j:j+1]
        print(b)
        ax = a.to_numpy()
        bx = b.to_numpy()
        
        aa = ax.reshape(-1,1)
        bb = bx.reshape(-1,1)
        print(aa.shape)
        print(bb.shape)
        
        d = sp.cdist(aa,bb,'euclidean')
        print(d)

### I leave out the part were distances.append(d) since what come before it fails
```

This returns:

```
1272    [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]
Name: Fingerprint, dtype: object
4538    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 15.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 3.0]
Name: Geopos Ack, dtype: object
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-368-e29e9515d73a> in <module>
     14         print(bb.shape)
     15 
---> 16         d = sp.cdist(aa,bb,'euclidean')
     17         print(d)
     18 

~\Anaconda3\envs\conda-qgis\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in cdist(XA, XB, metric, *args, **kwargs)
   2802         metric_name = _METRIC_ALIAS.get(mstr, None)
   2803         if metric_name is not None:
-> 2804             XA, XB, typ, kwargs = _validate_cdist_input(XA, XB, mA, mB, n,
   2805                                                         metric_name, **kwargs)
   2806 

~\Anaconda3\envs\conda-qgis\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in _validate_cdist_input(XA, XB, mA, mB, n, metric_name, **kwargs)
    245         typ = types[types.index(XA.dtype)] if XA.dtype in types else types[0]
    246         # validate data
--> 247         XA = _convert_to_type(XA, out_type=typ)
    248         XB = _convert_to_type(XB, out_type=typ)
    249 

~\Anaconda3\envs\conda-qgis\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in _convert_to_type(X, out_type)
    182 
    183 def _convert_to_type(X, out_type):
--> 184     return np.ascontiguousarray(X, dtype=out_type)
    185 
    186 

~\Anaconda3\envs\conda-qgis\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in ascontiguousarray(a, dtype)
    175 
    176     """
--> 177     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
    178 
    179 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Where did I go wrong? All arrays consist of floats and the shapes look right.

I know another approach would be to use `pairwise_distance` from `sklearn` but I did not manage to apply it to my dataframes.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Data**:

```
df_sample = 
{'Fingerprint': {1272: [0.0,
   4.0,
   8.0,
   15.0,
   10.0,
   8.0,
   2.54,
   2.0,
   4.91,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.59,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.0],
  657: [1.44,
   12.0,
   10.0,
   5.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.23,
   4.36,
   15.0],
  806: [4.58,
   13.09,
   15.46,
   3.59,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   6.31]}}
```

and

```
DF = 
{'barcode': {4538: 'A4060462000516278',
  5043: 'A4050494272716275',
  11663: 'A4070271111316245',
  2701: 'A4060462848716270',
  825: 'A4060454573516274',
  8679: 'A4060462010016274',
  11700: 'A4060462080916270',
  8594: 'A4060461067716272',
  8707: 'A4060454363916275',
  1071: 'A4060463723916275'},
 'Geopos Ack': {4538: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   15.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.5,
   0.0,
   3.0],
  5043: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   3.0,
   0.0],
  11663: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  2701: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   13.0,
   16.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   7.0],
  825: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  8679: [0.0,
   4.0,
   9.0,
   15.0,
   10.0,
   3.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   9.0],
  11700: [0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   8.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   6.0],
  8594: [12.0,
   16.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   5.0],
  8707: [7.0,
   5.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.0,
   15.0],
  1071: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   15.5,
   6.0,
   3.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0]}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected output is (I guess of shape (10,3)?) and not able to follow your code to pinpoint the source of the error you're getting. Still, what do you say about the following: `a = np.array(df["Geopos Ack"].tolist()); b = np.array(df_sample.Fingerprint.tolist()); print(cdist(a, b))`?